# Is an exponential family closed under convolution?

Tags: mathematical-statistics, exponential-family

Let 
$$
y = x_1 + x_2 + x_3
$$
where $x_1, x_2, x_3$ are draws of random variables of the same family and different parameters:  $p(x_1| \theta_1), p(x_2| \theta_2), p(x_3| \theta_3)$

We know that, for some distributions that are closed under convolution, then the distribution over $y$ belongs to the same distribution.

My question concerns the case where $x_i$ belong to some exponential family of distributions: does the sum of random variables from an exponential family also belong to some exponential family?

Comment: Maybe you should tag this as self-study?  (And, the short answer is YES)

Comment: Use the MGF uniqueness theorem

Comment: Not hard to think of some counter examples. 1 parameter exponentials are members of the exponential family.

Comment: @AdamO This is an example rather than a counter example, isn't it?

Comment: @alberto no, iid exponential sums are not exponential.

Comment: @AdamO I know about some counter examples, but does the distributon of the sum at least belong to the Exponential Family? Oh, I see the confusion, I mean the family, not the expontial distribution!

Comment: @alberto you still aren't grasping. The exponential distribution is a member of the exponential family. As I said, it is an *example*. Your assertion is wrong. In math, a counter example suffices to disprove a claim, so your "other examples" should have discredit the thought immediately.

Comment: Well, the sum of (independent) variables pertaining to *some* exponential family belongs to *some other* exponential family!  This is proved in (from memory) Bickel&Doksum, for instance

Comment: @ketil that's what I meant, thanks! I'll try to get the book.

Comment: @AdamO You and kjetil and alberto appear to be talking at cross-purposes: the issue concerns whether alberto means **the** [family of Exponential distributions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_distribution) or **an** [exponential family of distributions.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_family)  Notice the distinctions between "the" and "an," as well as the different capitalization.  The meanings are quite different!  Alberto, please edit your question to clarify your meaning.

Comment: @whuber Unless I'm mistaken, wouldn't the geometric distribution be yet another counter example? Wouldn't the Bernoulli? I think some conditions need to be imposed about the dimension of the parameter(s).

Comment: @AdamO I'm not sure how you are interpreting the question where you talk of "counter-example."  One natural interpretation--but not necessarily the only one--is whether *all possible sums of variables taken from a given exponential family* themselves form another exponential family.  As such, if $\theta$ is the parameter in the first family with $\theta\in\Theta$, then the parameter $(\theta_1,\theta_2)$ in the family of sums can be viewed as an element in a quotient space of the product $\Theta\times\Theta$, which may have strictly larger dimension than $\Theta$.

Comment: I would guess the sum of binomial distributions with different p values might fall outside the exponential family, but lacking the will to investigate/prove right now.

Comment: @whuber ok I see now. Yeah I was reading a slightly different question. Apologies.

Comment: @Paul I believe you can make short work of this by considering the cumulant generating functions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The property that you describe refers to [stable distributions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stable_distribution)

You can study these convolutions of pdf's by products of characteristic functions.  For instance:

- The **Cauchy-Lorentz** distribution is a stable distribution $$E(e^{itX}) = e^{it\mu_X+\sigma_X\vert t\vert}$$ and $$E(e^{itX+Y}) = e^{it\mu_X+\sigma_X\vert t\vert} e^{it\mu_X+\sigma_X\vert t\vert} =e^{it(\mu_X+\mu_Y)+(\sigma_X+\sigma_Y)\vert t\vert} = e^{it\mu_Z+\sigma_Z\vert t\vert} $$ with $\mu_Z=\mu_X+\mu_Y$ and $\sigma_Z=\sigma_X+\sigma_y$
- but, for instance, the **Gamma** distribution is not a stable distribution $$E(e^{itX}) = (1-it\theta_X)^{k_X}$$ and $$E(e^{itX+Y}) = (1-it\theta_X)^{k_X} (1-it\theta_Y)^{k_Y} \neq (1-it\theta_Z)^{k_Z}  $$ where we can not make this final step ([unless $\theta_X = \theta_Y$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/250059/sum-of-independent-gamma-distributions-is-a-gamma-distribution))

---

So for a particular distribution that is in the exponential family it is not (generally) true that is a stable distribution.

Still you may wonder whether the sum of any two distributions in the exponential family could be any other distribution in the exponential family.

- There is no general description of the characteristic function of an exponential family distribution $f(x) = h(x)g(\theta) e^{\eta(\theta) \cdot T(x)}$, and trying to work out the convolution for the general case is messy (and I don't think it works).

  Possibly one could work out a particular case to show that a convolution is yielding some distribution that is not a exponential family.
- If the sufficient statistic T(x) is a linear function then at least the cumulant generating function for T *might* be used to proof some stability property:

  $$k(u \vert \eta) = A(\eta + u) + A(\eta)$$

  by using the property $k(X+Y) = k(X) + k(y)$. However, I am not sure about the inverse step, whether the cumulant generating function $k(X) + k(y)$ is necessarily referring to a valid distribution from the exponential family. But at least this is an interesting notion.